# change widget's size through blueprints

Tags: unreal-4, ui-design, blueprints

I want to change the size X of my 'Horizontal Box' widget's through blueprints but cannot figure out how to do that... the properties that I want to be able to control from blueprints are marked red below:

[image]

To give you some context, I need this to instantiate my widget dynamically. I first add a bunch of child widgets which works just great, but I also need to kinda resize the quad in the background to fit in size the child widgets that I am 'spawning'. Isn't there really any way to do this? Because this seems a super-basic thing to do as from my point of view but can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the X and Y values, you need to click the "Size To Content" box under them which will do this for you.

There is a function called "Set ZOrder" as well.  Get a reference to Self, get the Slot As Canvas Slot then call it.

[image: Unreal Engine UE4 Set ZOrder]

Comment: aaaah… slot as canvas slot is the key... thanks a lot. that you are invalidating layout afterwards - is this something I should pay attention to as well or?

Comment: No, this image is something I found on the Unreal Engine forums where a similar question was asked.  You can just ignore it.

Comment: understood, thanks again